# On Fourier coefficients of Bianchi modular forms, l-ordinary

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

Let $f\in S_2(\Gamma_1(N))$ be a Hecke eigenform and $\ell$ a prime number does not divide $N$. Let $a_f(\ell)$ be the $\ell$-th Fourier coefficient of $f$. Then $a_f(\ell)$ is  is called $\ell$-ordinary if $a_f(\ell)$ is a $\ell$-adic unit.

For any Hecke eigenforms $f$, the Dirichlet density of the following set
$$
\{\ell:\text{ prime numbers }|f \text{ is }\ell\text{-ordinary }\}
$$
is 1. Here are the references:
[Reference Link 1](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ehida/AbNSS.pdf),
[Reference Link 2](http://www.numdam.org/item/AIF_2002__52_2_351_0/)

> **Question.** Is there the same result for Bianchi modular forms (automorphic forms on $\operatorname{GL}(2)$ over imaginary quadratic fields)?

Comment: I think this should be known (assuming of course that $f$ is not a theta lift, in which case it's false). Prop. 2.2 of the Fischman paper quotes Thm 15 [this Serre paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1981__54__123_0.pdf). The only modular forms specific input of the proof is Prop 17, which requires knowing that the $l$-adic Galois representation $G_K \to \mathrm{GL}_2(\overline{\mathbb Q}_\ell)$ associated to $f$ is absolutely irreducible when restricted to any finite extension of $K$. But this is known for Bianchi modular forms.

Comment: Crossposted from MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4100189/11323

Comment: I think this might be a bit more delicate than it looks. The argument of Serre is based on bounding how often we can have $a_\ell(f) = 0$. If the coefficient field is $\mathbf{Q}$ then it follows from the Hasse--Weil bound that $\ell$ can only divide $a_\ell(f)$ if it is zero, but this breaks down if the coefficient field is larger. The argument of Hida applies to the case when the form is for $GL2/K$ and the coeff field is equal to K, and shows only that there is a density 1 set of primes $\ell$ for which $f$ is ordinary at *some* prime above $\ell$ ("partially ordinary" in Hida's notation).